# How to remove user input from a text box and allow javascript text to populate it

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a quick question on how to look up making "text field box (the way Qty looks)" that's in a form but without a user to be able to insert it. I have a javascript file that's supposed to calculate this automatically and populate the text box with the appropriate information but I can't have the user changing the tax/subtotal/total. I have tried to just use innerHTML but that just gets rid of the text box look that I'm aiming for.

> 

```
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><span>Price: $59.99</span></legend>



                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><span>Qty:</span></legend>
                        <input type="number" id="bookQty" min="0" />
                        <label for="bookQty">
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><span id="subTotal">Subtotal: </span></legend>
                        <input type="number" id="subTotal" min="0" />
                        <label for="subTotal"></label>

                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><span id="tax">Tax(5%):</span></legend>


                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><span id="total">Total: </span></legend>


                    </fieldset>
            </form>
```

[image: Form]

Comment: Please add your code or a small replicable example so that the community can assist you properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give your input the `readonly` attribute, which makes the element not mutable, meaning the user can not edit it.

Example:

```html
  <input type="number" value="Some value" readonly="readonly" id="subtotal"/>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for I just didn't know the word for it!